# return long double value in visual studio

Tags: c++, c

I wrote power function code in visual studio 2012:

```
#include<stdio.h>
long double myPow( long double base, unsigned int exp);
int main(){
    long double base, m;
    unsigned int exp;
    scanf("%Lf%u",&base ,&exp);
    m=myPow(base, exp);
    printf("%.3Lf",m);
    //getch();
    return 0;
}
 long double myPow( long double base, unsigned int exp){
    static long double power=1;
    if (base==1)
        return base;
    if(exp==1)
        return power*base;
    else{
        power*=base;
        myPow(base,exp-1);
    }
}
```

but the output in vs always is **-1.#IO**.

what s the problem?

Comment: Do you not get a warning from this code? "not all control paths return a value"

Comment: I also did not get any warnings from gcc without adding extra flags to gcc command line. So just add 'return' on the line with the recursive call to myPow. And enable warning flags on your compiler.

Comment: How could I enable it in visual studio?

Comment: my code with int signature for myPow works((by using integer numbers) but for flaot signatures and mantissa doesn t

Answer (score 3):

You need to *return* `myPow(base, exp-1)`.

This is a very poor way to compute a power. Look up the algorithm that involves squaring.

Comment: thanks . and what s the difference if I write just myPow(base, exp-1) without return?

Comment: @irani1995: The value from the recursive call is discarded, and the function doesn't return a value, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley but my code with int signatures instead of long double for myPow works

Comment: @irani1995 I doubt it. You might have got lucky with a particular test value. Wrong code is still wrong.

Comment: @irani1995: When your code has undefined behavior, it makes no sense to say "it works", because there is nothing in particular which it is expected to do. If you mean it works the way you expected it to, then your expectations are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you change everything under the else statment in your function to:

> while (exp>0)                 {                      power *= base;                      --exp;                 }            return power;

It should work

Comment: yeah I know but I wanna to use Recursion functions intentionly